# Getting error while adding connection factory in HermesJMS

Tags: activemq-classic, soapui, hermes-jms

I am getting an error while adding 'Connection factory' in 'HermesJMS'. 
What could be reason for this error?

Error:

> 'javax.naming.NamingException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized.'

Comment: Do you want show the hermes-config.xml to review?

Comment: @Rao, - Thank you, it is working fine now. I have updated few JAR Files.

Comment: Glad you could proceed